# How to speed up VBA to Extract data from Word to Excel

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to stackoverflow and a newbie to VBA coding. At my work, we are supplied with shipment data in the form of Ms Word which is not very useful. I have found a way to transfer the data using VBA and have a code that is fully functional. However, the data set contains hundreds of thousands of records. I tried running a month's worth of data with 200k records and it took 5 days. Just wondering if there is anything in my code that I could be improved to speed up the process. I've tried turning off screen updates, events, calculations but it didn't do much. Thanks in advance for your help.

```
Sub Word_to_Excel()

Dim FName As String, FD As FileDialog
Dim wdApp As Object
Dim wdDoc As Object
Dim WDR, WDCheck, ShipmentID As Object
Dim ExR As Range
Dim file
Dim Path As String
Dim ImportDate As Object
Dim ImportValue As String
Dim ShipmentIDcheck As String
Dim objResult



    Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

    Set ExR = Selection ' current location in Excel Sheet

    ' Select Folder containing word documents
    Set FD = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)
    FD.Show
    FName = FD.SelectedItems(1)

    file = Dir(FName & "\*.docx")

    Set wdApp = CreateObject("Word.Application")

    ' Open word document in the folder, run macro, close it and open the next word document until there are none left
    Do While file <> ""
    wdApp.Documents.Open Filename:=FName & "\" & file
    wdApp.ActiveWindow.ActivePane.View.Type = 1
    wdApp.Visible = True

    ' Once the word doc is open, go to beginning of document and search for CTY/SITE/SORT:
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=6
    wdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wdApp.Selection.Find.Execute "CTY/SITE/SORT:"
    Set WDCheck = wdApp.Selection

    ' If "CTY/SITE/SORT:" is found, then look for Shipment ID
    Do While WDCheck = "CTY/SITE/SORT:"

    ' Find first shipment
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=11
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set ShipmentID = wdApp.Selection
    ShipmentIDcheck = Replace(ShipmentID, " ", "")

    ' Transfer information from Word to Excel for a Shipment ID and go to the next one.
    ' Shipment ID should be a string that is 11 characters long
    ' If Shipment ID no longer exist, go to next page by searching for the next CTY/SITE/SORT:
    Do While Len(Trim(ShipmentIDcheck)) = 11
        i = i + 1
        ExR(i, 1) = file
        ExR(i, 2) = ShipmentIDcheck

    ' Consignee Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveUp Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 3) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 8) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Name
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 13) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Quantity
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=10, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 19) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Weight
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 20) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Value
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=12, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 21) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Broker
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 23) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Street
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 4) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Street
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 9) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Street
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=23, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 14) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Description
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=8
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=40, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 18) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee City
    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 5) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 6) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Consignee Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 7) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer City
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 10) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 11) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Importer Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 12) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper City
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=13, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 15) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Province
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 16) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Shipper Postal
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=6, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 17) = Trim(WDR)

    ' Country of Origin
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=29
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=21, Extend:=1
    Set WDR = wdApp.Selection
    ExR(i, 22) = Trim(WDR)

    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.MoveDown Unit:=5, Count:=2
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=1
    wdApp.Selection.MoveRight Unit:=1, Count:=11, Extend:=1
    Set ShipmentID = wdApp.Selection
    ' Remove spaces from selection. Selection is then used to check if it is a shipment ID.
    ' If it is, then data for that shipment ID is transferred. If not, macro will go to the next page in the Word Doc.
    ShipmentIDcheck = Replace(ShipmentID, " ", "")

    ActiveCell.Offset(1).Select

    Loop

    'Simulate keyboard press "NUMLOCK" to prevent screen from locking
    objResult = objShell.SendKeys("{NUMLOCK}")

    wdApp.Selection.HomeKey Unit:=5
    wdApp.Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    wdApp.Selection.Find.Execute "CTY/SITE/SORT:"
    Set WDCheck = wdApp.Selection

    Loop

    wdApp.ActiveDocument.Close SaveChanges:=wdDoNotSaveChanges
    ActiveWorkbook.Save
    file = Dir()

    Loop

    wdApp.Quit

    MsgBox "Data extraction completed at:" & vbNewLine & Format(Now, "mmmm d, yyyy hh:mm AM/PM")

End Sub
```

This is how the data is formatted in Ms Word. There are multiple word documents containing pages and pages of this dataset per day. Number of shipments per page varies. But the format are the same throughout. There are no tables in the word documents, just text separated by spaces. CTY/SITE/SORT: is unique to every page and I used it as an anchor point. if the macro finds it, then it goes down 11 lines and takes the first shipment ID and the other information. It then checks for the next shipment ID. If it is not there, then it goes to the next page and repeats the process.

```
REPORT NUM   : ABC1234                                   OPERATIONS SYSTEM                                       PAGE NUM:   2      
 CTY/SITE/SORT: CA 00123                                    SUMMARY CARGO                                         RUN TIME: 07:33:43 
 SORT DATE    :                                            INBOUND - SCAN                                         RUN DATE: 01AUG19  
                                                                                                                  OPER ID : ABC123  
 MVMT: 12345678   MVMT DT: 01AUG19    MAWB:                  PROD TYP:      DTY TYP:      IMP CTY:      EXP CTY:      BL TYP:        
                        COURIER REMISSION  MANIFEST               EXPORT SITE: US 12345                                

 GCCN ID:               EXPECTED SHPTS:           EXPECTED PKGS:             EXPECTED WEIGHT:                                        

 CUSTOMS NUM     CONSIGNEE NAME           IMPORTER NAME           SHIPPER NAME        CSA    QTY     WGT(LBS)   VALUE  BROKER        
 SHIPMENT ID                                                                               DESCRIPTION           (CAD) CTRY OF ORIGIN
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
             JOHN SMITH              ABC COMPANY             XYZ COMPANY                      1          1.1      1000.00 UNCONSIGNED
 ABC12345678 123 MAIN STREET         345 RANDOM ROAD         UNIVERSITY OF WASHINGTO       BICYCLE PARTS                             
             VANCOUVER     BC V1A1A1 VANCOUVER     BC V2B1B2 SEATTLE       WA 981234                            US                   
       TOTAL FOR DUTY TYPE COURIER REMISSION                                                                                         
       TOTAL SHIPMENTS:                      4                                                                                       
       TOTAL PACKAGES :                      4                                                                                       
       TOTAL WEIGHT   :                     70.9 LBS                                                                                 
       TOTAL VALUES   :                   4000.00                                                                                         
* * *
```

Comment: Is the word document laid out with tables? If so I'd consider plain copy-pasting the Word tables into a spreadsheet, and try processing that instead.

Comment: no tables. it is laid out into columns and separated by spaces.

Comment: Then I try text import. Anything but line-by-line, column-by-column processing ;-)

Comment: [the-macro-recorder-curse](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/06/30/the-macro-recorder-curse/) can be cured! And 200K data should be stored in a database!

Answer (score 5):

### Declarations

My first comment is `Option explicit`. **Every. Single. Time.**

Your first line of code is :

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
```

Why? `objshell` is not declared or used. And while on the matter of declarations:

```
Dim WDR, WDCheck, ShipmentID As Object
```

declares `WDR` and `WDCheck` as Variant, not Object.

Youi are writing a utility tool - using *early binding* instead of *late binding* will improve the code. (`Dim wdApp as Word.Application` : `Set wdApp = New Word.Application`, assuming you are running this from Excel).

### Macro recorder

To me it is obvious you used the macro recorder and then simply copied the code to get what you wanted. In order to improve your code, look at each step that has been recorded (a couple of lines each time) to work out what is really happening

You open a word document, but do not assign that open document to the declared variable `wdDoc`. Which should be declared as `Word.Document` not `Object`. Hint: `Word.Application.Documents.Open` returns a Document.

Once you start looking at the recorded code and making sensible changes, you will stop working with the nebulous `Selection` and start working directly with defined objects that you can control better.

### Approach

A good approach is to first clean the input data. This can be as simple as identifying the block of text to be imported, copying that to an intermediate work area (perhaps a temporary word document, or a work area in your excel file) and then setting up the data format to suit your next step (the direct import).

What I have inferred from your code is that each column is separated by multiple spaces to create a nicely formatted output. So you can have two approaches here:

- replace those spaces with a known delimiter
- use the fixed column widths to do a text input into Excel (noted by
  @MathieuGuindon in the comments)

The first approach is useful if there is no consistency between the documents. The second is useful if there is this consistency.

Either way, at the end of these steps you have a consistent form of input data that you can now directly import into Excel.

I have deliberately not included any example code. The initial steps of refactoring the macro-recorded code is great learning experience for yourself and is something that will give you good insight into how you can improve your own code.

Looking forwards to the seeing the refactored code as a new article here for further review!